# Render view inside a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a website which requires something like this:

index.html.erb:

```
<div>
  <%= render "hello" %>
</div>
```

hello.html.erb:

> whatever content is other here

That doesn't work since hello is not a partial. But is there a way to make render work anyways? (maybe not using render ^^)

And no, changing hello.html.erb to a partial is not an option, "hello" is a separate page which CAN be displayed on it's own.

I could use an iframe... but I'd rather stick to rendering the page server-side :)

Comment: you can use string and render that as html if possible

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `render template`:

```
render template: 'hello' # should render hello.html.erb
```

or

```
render template: 'products/show' # render views/products/show.html.erb
```